# Data Binding ListView child class properties from a list of parent class

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having problem displaying child class properties through a list of parent class.

Xaml

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="lvTest" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectionMode="Single" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="630" Height="270">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Index" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=index}" Width="100" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=c.name}" Width="100" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="age" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=c.age}" Width="100" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<parent> parentList;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GenerateList();

        lvTest.ItemsSource = parentList;
    }

    private void GenerateList()
    {
        parentList = new List<parent>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            parent p = new parent();
            p.index = i;

            child c = new child();
            c.name = "Name_" + (i + 1).ToString();
            c.age = i;

            parentList.Add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Classes

```
public class parent
{
    public int index { get; set; }
    public child c { get; set; }
}

public class child
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

I can't display the **"name"** and **"age"** property of the **child** class but I have no problem in accessing the **index** property of the **parent** class.

Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems you forget to "save" you `child` instance in `parent` object:

```
child c = new child();
c.name = "Name_" + (i + 1).ToString();
c.age = i;

p.c = c; // THIS!
```

Comment: Oh ya. Stupid mistake. Thanks

Comment: Don't worry, we all sometimes make mistakes :) Please, mark as an answer if it will help you.